write Gulp-sass filtes to different folders
hello to everyone,
I use the Foundation Framework (6.8.1) for the frontend development of TYPO3 websites. The Foundation Asset folder is in the project root, from there I would like to render some special CSS into the respective folders of the element when making changes to the SCSS file.
The move itself works - but when changes are made to the SCSS, these files are not updated in the respective folder.
Can someone help me and tell me how to structure my "gulpfile.js" better / correctly?
I would be very happy if someone can give me the right tips for a better structuring.
I have extended the standard "gulpfile.js" like this:
const gulp         = require('gulp');
const sass         = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();
const sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

const includePaths = [
    'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
    'node_modules/motion-ui/src'
];

The SCSS/CSS files that are stored in the template
function sassBuild() {
    return gulp.src(['scss/main.scss', 'scss/fonts.scss'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: includePaths,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../../../packages/projekt/Resources/Public/Css'));
};

SCSS/CSS files that are stored in multiple extensions
function sassBuildSlider() {
    return gulp.src(['scss/slider.scss'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths : includePaths,
            outputStyle  : 'compressed'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../../../packages/erweiterungen/ContentBlocks/ContentElements/slider/Assets'));
};

... and the functions that trigger it
function serve() {
    browserSync.init({server : "./"});
    gulp.watch("scss/*.scss", sassBuild, sassBuildAccordion, sassBuildSlider, sassBuildIconWidthHeadline);
    gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

gulp.task('sass', sassBuild);
gulp.task('sass', sassBuildAccordion);
gulp.task('sass', sassBuildSlider);
gulp.task('sass', sassBuildIconWidthHeadline);
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', serve));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', serve));



You're passing multiple functions as arguments to gulp.watch(), but it expects a single callback function or a series of tasks:

gulp.watch("scss/*.scss", gulp.series(sassBuild, sassBuildSlider, ...));


You have multiple tasks named sass, which is likely a mistake since task names should be unique. I think you can simplify using series again:

gulp.task('sass', gulp.series(sassBuild, sassBuildSlider, ...));

If it's important to run tasks one after another in a specified order, then use gulp.series(). If the order is not important, then you can execute tasks simultaneously using gulp.parallel().

Hej invulner, thanks for your answer. But where does this change need to be made? Does your code go under the function or into it?

The first example with watch should simply replace your watch task for scss/*.scss, within the serve function. The second example with the sass task should just replace all of your sass tasks.
